# Disable certain Docker run options

Tags: security, docker, command-line-interface

I'm currently working on a setup to make Docker available on a high performance cluster (HPC). The idea is that every user in our group should be able to reserve a machine for a certain amount of time and be able to use Docker in a "normal way". Meaning accessing the Docker Daemon via the Docker CLI.

To do that, the user would be added to the Docker group. But this imposes a big security problem for us, since this basically means that the user has root privileges on that machine.

The new idea is to make use of the user namespace mapping option (as described in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#/daemon-user-namespace-options). As I see it, this would tackle our biggest security concern that the root in a container is the same as the root on the host machine.

But as long as users are able to bypass this via --userns=host , this doesn't increase security in any way.

**Is there a way to disable this and other Docker run options?**

Comment: You can write a shell script that will launch the `docker run...`, but this looks like a flawed concept

Comment: I think changing or replacing only the CLI doesn't help that much, because the Docker Daemon socket would still accept these options. So you could just use another program to interact with the socket. The change should disable the option in the Docker Daemon itself.

Comment: Why do they need access to the Docker CLI? If that requirement can be removed, you can give them access to a script that spins up any image as a container with much less of a security risk.

Comment: The idea is to provide the full Docker functionality minus stuff like privileged containers and using the host user namespace. We have different people with completely different use cases we would like to support. So at some point I would imagine the approach of a 'script' to be a reimplementation of the whole Docker CLI

Comment: Is there some reason that sudo is unfeasible compared to using the docker group?

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in [issue 22223](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22223#issuecomment-212872877)

> There are a whole lot of ways in which users can elevate privileges through docker run, eg by using `--privileged`.
>   **You can stop this** by:
>
> - either not directly providing access to the daemon in production, and using scripts,

(which is not what you want here)

> - or by using an [**auth plugin**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_authorization/) to disallow some options.

That is:

```
dockerd --authorization-plugin=plugin1
```

Which can lead to:

[image: https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/images/authz_deny.png]

Comment: Here is a basic docker authorization plugin example: https://github.com/twistlock/authz